# How to use a grove speaker without using delayMicroseconds?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, frequency, sound

is there another way to replace **delayMicroseconds(BassTab[note_index])** as I cannot have delays in my loop due to the need of having multi-tasking in my sketch.

Grove speaker: http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/Grove-Speaker-p-1445.html

```
/*macro definition of Speaker pin*/
#define SPEAKER 8

int BassTab[]={1911,1702,1516,1431,1275,1136,1012};//bass 1~7

void setup() 
{
  pinMode(SPEAKER,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(SPEAKER,LOW);
}
void loop()
{
    sound(5);
    delay(5000); //Wait 5second and play the sound again
}

void sound(uint8_t note_index)
{
  for(int i=0;i<100;i++)   
  {
    digitalWrite(SPEAKER,HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(BassTab[note_index]);
    digitalWrite(SPEAKER,LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(BassTab[note_index]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a small amplifier and speaker - what you put into the SIG pin gets amplified and sent out the speaker.

Instead of doing the audio generation manually like that I would suggest using the `tone()` function which will generate an audio tone at a desired frequency in the background.

- https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Tone